# Need PhotoBooth Mac feature in iphone app

Tags: iphone, opencv, image-manipulation, distortion

Have a look on following application

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fatbooth/id372268904?mt=8

i think they are using the same feature provided my PhotoBooth MAC.

Please suggest any api or any other possible solution so that I can build an iphone application

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any success here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Image (certainly used by Photo Booth on the Mac) is not a public API on the iPhone. To achieve something similar, you would have to use OpenGL and write your own shaders (or do something like OpenGL mesh distortion).

Comment: But as i can see on itunes, there are lots of iphone applications doing the same functionality what actually Photo Booth does, there must be a 3rd party api provided by any organization. Because using own OpenGL logics lots of developers cannot achieve same functionality of PhotoBooth (Mac application)

Comment: Why not? I myself have such an app on the store and I built it with OpenGL shaders.

Comment: oh thats great sir :) . can you please provide us any sample. so that i can start the development process. Or kindly suggest any appropriate way so that i can work in right direction