# How to make an app similar to Fat Booth for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, image-manipulation

I'm just curious how they make apps like Fat Booth for the iPhone? I've been learning/developing iphone apps for the last couple of months but have never ventured into anything image/photo/game based, how on earth do you do image manipulation within objective c? Is it with similar libraries to Cocos 2D or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quartz 2D/OpenGLES geometric distortions on images (preferrably using CGImage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459108/quartz-2d-opengles-geometric-distortions-on-images-preferrably-using-cgimage)

Comment: See also [Need PhotoBooth Mac feature in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829395/need-photobooth-mac-feature-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Hi benhowdle..i see your question and i now i make fatbooth application..So r u made this fatbooth application in android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cocos2d is for game animations. what you want is image processing.

entering something along the lines of "objective-c image processing" into google is a good place to start. projects like http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/ will give you an idea of how you manipulate image data in objective-c. And you never know, there may be an open source library that does the kind of morphing you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I just released an app on the app store that internally had to implement a rudimentary version of FatBooth in order to achieve the final effect. Take a look at [Displacement Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping) for an idea as to how you can get images to bend, expand, shrink, bloat, etc. FatBooth might have approached it a different way, but this is certainly one approach that would have worked just fine for FatBooth.